# How to design a dialog bubble or shape in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

How do I design this shape in Photoshop?:

[image]

The box is rounded and it has an arrow pointer at the bottom.

I am not bothered about the color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Round Rectangle and Polygon tools.

You first need to create a round rectangle (using the Round Rectangle Tool):

[image]

Then change to the Polygon Tool, and choose "Sides: 3" in the menu at the top. Using the Path Selection Tool, click on your round rectangle and pressing shift (so the shape is added to your current one) draw the triangle:

[image]

You can re-position each of the shapes using the Path Selection Tool. Once you are happy with your result, apply the gradient and stroke.

Comment: Thank you! When I try to gradient and stroke but it only apply on each layer/shape... but I want apply on a dialog bubble

Comment: If you have drawn them on separate layers (you have to use shift to draw them in the same) you can still merge the shapes - in CS6 select both layers, right click and "Merge shapes".

Comment: Oh I managed to do, I made a mistake. I need to draw a triangle on a current round rectangle :)

Comment: I can re-position each of the shapes using the Path Selection Tool but how to make sure rectangle is 100% at the center between round rectangle automatically?

Comment: If you have both shapes selected, you can "Align horizontal centers". It's one of the options that appear on the top bar when you use the Move Tool (V).